# Haskell - Check if all items in list are greater than 1

Tags: list, function, haskell

I need to return a Boolean True if all items are greater than 1, otherwise False. This is my attempt...

```
greaterOne :: Ord a=>a->Bool
greaterOne x = x > 1

checkLis :: Ord a=>[a]->Bool
checkLis [] = True
checkLis (x:xs)
    | greaterOne x = checkLis xs
    | otherwise = False
```

This is the error I get, I keep trying to fix it but to no avail...

```
Could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal ‘1’
from the context (Ord a)
  bound by the type signature for greaterOne :: Ord a => a -> Bool
  at pract.hs:23:15-28
Possible fix:
  add (Num a) to the context of
    the type signature for greaterOne :: Ord a => a -> Bool
In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘1’
In the expression: x > 1
In an equation for ‘greaterOne’: greaterOne x = x > 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a moment, just consider this expression,

```
x > 1
```

we know for sure that, `1` is a number and we need to compare it with `x` and return the result. But we don't know the type of `x`. What if `x` is actually a String? Then the expression will fail. But Haskell's type system is strong and it senses the confusion here and asks you to fix it manually. It even offers you a hint,

```
Possible fix:
  add (Num a) to the context of
    the type signature for greaterOne :: Ord a => a -> Bool
```

So, all you have to do is, explicitly specify that `a` is an instance of the class `Num`, as suggested by GHC, like this

```
checkLis :: Ord a => Num a => [a] -> Bool
checkLis [] = True
......
greaterOne :: Ord a => Num a => a -> Bool
greaterOne x = x > 1
```

Now, we are saying, `a` is not just an Ordered data-type, but it is actually of class `Num`.

---

You can actually use the built-in function [`all`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) to do this.

```
> all greaterOne [2, 2, 3]
True
> all greaterOne [1, 2, 3]
False
```

The `all` function checks if the function passed as the first parameter, evaluates to `True` for every element in the list.

---

We can actually do the same thing with just the partial expression, like this

```
Prelude> all (> 1) [2, 2, 3]
True
Prelude> all (> 1) [1, 2, 3]
False
```